# VFS for zip files on android

Tags: android, zip, vfs

I need a library that can open zip file like virtual file system **programmatically** and work with inner files and directories (read JSON, install apk). Is there are any library for that? The main thing, i shouldn't extract zip.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the problem , You can use it. https://github.com/hzy3774/AndroidP7zip

Comment: As i understood it doesn't use any vfs, with this library i can only decompress to file system.